# How to Create a Customised Header File in C and Use It in a Program

Tags: c

I want to create a header file in C and add it to a library. How do I create the header file and add/access it to/from the library.

Comment: What do you mean by "add it to library to use"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some header:

```
//header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

int ThisReturnsOne() {
    return 1;
}

#endif //HEADER_H
```

Some c file:

```
//file.c
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    int x;
    x = ThisReturnsOne(); //x == 1
}
```

So the contents of "header.h" are available to "file.c". This assumes they are in the same directory.

Edit: Added include guards. This prevents the header file from being included in the same translation unit twice.

Comment: No include guards?  I suggest you add them to your example, as it's a best practice.  EDIT: Thanks.

Comment: It was an exceptionally trivial example off the top of my head. Added them now, though.

Comment: "Edit: Added include guards. This prevents the header file from being included in the same project twice."  Correction: "in the same *translation unit* twice".  This basically means "in the same compiler invocation".

Comment: @strager To be pedantic, no it doesn't - `mycc a.c b.c` is two translation units, one compiler invocation.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, Yes, I know that.  I used 'basically' to mean 'this is probably how you think of it when compiling, but it's a simplified view which is technically incorrect'.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file with the extension `.h`, for example `mystuff.h`. Put the desired header contents in there, and include it in your sources via `#include "mystuff.h"`.

Comment: This could get messy, depending on the include paths and where the header is stored.  Such is C.

Comment: Luckily, it's C. It could be worse.